# How to redirect if form submission is successful and remains on the page its false using js

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect, submission

Here is my code. I want to redirect the page after successful form submission and it remains on that page and the user needs to fix the error

```
<form id="form_1" name="form" action="#" method="POST">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="group1" value="true">Yes
    <input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="group1" value="false">No
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="group2" value="true">Yes
    <input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="group2" value="false">No
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  var form = document.querySelector('#form_1');
  var radioList = form.querySelectorAll('.radio_btn');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    for (var i = 0, length1 = radioList.length; i < length1; i++) {
      if (radioList[i].getAttribute('value') == 'false' && radioList[i].checked) {
        alert("error");
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
        window.location.assign("http://worldlivecricket.com");
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this using `jquery`

```
$("#form_1").on("submit",function(e){
   if(your validation) {
      // redirect 
   } else {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

here `e.preventDefault();` will stop the page from reloading